# Ansible lookup yaml file fetch nested list via dynamic key

Tags: ansible, yaml, lookup, var

Basically, I have a YAML file,

```
  ---
  mock_key:
    mock_sub_key:
     - my-value-1
     - my-value-2
    random_other_key:
     - random-value-1
     - random-value-2
    more_sub_key:
     - value-1
```

And I want to look up a list of `mock_sub_key` or `random_other_key`, etc dynamically based on the parameter passed to the map attribute, i.e, `dynamic_key`,  `dynamic_sub_key`

```
# With Quote, Not Work
loop:  "{{ (lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') | from_yaml) | map(attribute='{{dynamic_key}}.{{dynamic_sub_key}}') }}"


# Without Quote, Not Work
loop: "{{ (lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') | from_yaml) | map(attribute={{dynamic_key}}.{{dynamic_sub_key}}) }}"

# Hardcoded,  Work
loop: "{{ (lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') | from_yaml) |map(attribute='mock_key.mock_sub_key') }}"
 
loop:  "{{ (lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') | from_yaml) map(attribute='mock_key.random_other_key') }}"
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to get an attribute from a file dynamically, if possible, how to achieve it. I use Ansible 2.8, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You never nest `{{...}}` template delimiters. You're **already** inside a template context. You can simply refer to variables by name. Since you're building a key from multiple variables, you can use Python-style string formatting, like this:

```
loop:  "{{ (lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') | from_yaml) | map(attribute='%s.%s' % (dynamic_key, dynamic_sub_key)) }}"
```

But that won't work, because the data in your file is a *dictionary*, not a *list*, so it doesn't make sense to pass it to the `map` filter. We can make it work by forcing the data into a list; here's a complete playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    dynamic_key: mock_key
    dynamic_sub_key: random_other_key
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            [(lookup('file', 'my_file.yaml') |from_yaml)] |
            map(attribute='%s.%s' % (dynamic_key, dynamic_sub_key))
          }}
```

The above playbook produces as output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "random-value-1",
            "random-value-2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more options:

- **include_vars**

Use *include_vars* from the file *my_file.yaml* and store the variable(s) into a dictionary, e.g. *my_vars*

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: my_file.yaml
        name: my_vars
```

gives

```yaml
  my_vars:
    mock_key:
      mock_sub_key:
      - my-value-1
      - my-value-2
      random_other_key:
      - random-value-1
      - random-value-2
```

Then loop the selected list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vars[dynamic_key][dynamic_sub_key] }}"
      vars:
        dynamic_key: mock_key
        dynamic_sub_key: random_other_key
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: random-value-1
  msg: random-value-2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: my_file.yaml
        name: my_vars

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vars[dynamic_key][dynamic_sub_key] }}"
      vars:
        dynamic_key: mock_key
        dynamic_sub_key: random_other_key
```

---

- **vars_files**

Use *vars_files* from the file *my_file.yaml*

```yaml
  vars_files:
    - my_file.yaml
```

and use the lookup plugins *varnames* and *vars* to get the dictionary *dynamic_key*

```yaml
my_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', dynamic_key)) }}"
dynamic_key: mock_key
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict:
    mock_sub_key:
    - my-value-1
    - my-value-2
    random_other_key:
    - random-value-1
    - random-value-2
```

Then the loop below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict[dynamic_sub_key] }}"
      vars:
        my_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', dynamic_key)) }}"
        dynamic_key: mock_key
        dynamic_sub_key: random_other_key
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - my_file.yaml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict[dynamic_sub_key] }}"
      vars:
        my_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', dynamic_key)) }}"
        dynamic_key: mock_key
        dynamic_sub_key: random_other_key
```